# How to inject/evaluate JS in multiple pages of an iOS webview?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webview, wkwebview

Seems like android's WebViewClient has methods like: onProgressChanged()

Anything for ios' wkwebview? (or any other iOS webview)

Webview's `onNavigationStateChange`doesn't seem to help here.

Would like to evaluate JS on `www.example.com` & then on`www.example.com/about`.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean with `onNavigationStateChange`? This doesn't sound familiar to me.

You should implement WKNavigationDelegate. [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate].

If you want to load JS after loading an url, you can implement `webView(_, didFinish: WKNavigation)`. WKNavigation offers the api to check request / url.
To load some JS before navigation finished, you can try with `webView(WKWebView, decidePolicyFor: WKNavigationAction)` [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview]
or `webView(WKWebView, decidePolicyFor: WKNavigationResponse)` [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455643-webview].

Answer (score 1):

See [WKUserScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscript), which is designed specifically for this purpose. When creating the WKWebView, you'll add a WKUserContentController, which can add scripts using `addUserScript`.

Comment: i tried to add multi userScript but not working, it's replace userScript, not add more